# Need a query for a tree type table in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables that are related like this:

[image]

The tree is joined to itself using ParentId as foreign key. The Tree and Owner tables have a many to many relationship through the xrefOwnerTree table.

I'm trying to write a query/function where I give it a tree id, and it gives me back an OwnerId that is nearest in the hierarchy (going up).

This is what i have so far:

```
WITH c (TreeId, Parentid, level, BranchName, OwnerId) as 
(
   SELECT t.TreeId, t.Parentid, 0 as level, BranchName, o.OwnerId
   FROM Tree t
   JOIN xrefOwnerTree ot ON t.TreeID = ot.TreeId
   JOIN Owner o ON ot.OwnerId = o.OwnerId
   WHERE Parentid is null

   UNION ALL

   SELECT t2.TreeId, t2.parentid, c.level + 1, t2.BranchName, o2.OwnerId
   FROM Tree t2 
   JOIN xrefOwnerTree ot2 ON t2.TreeID = ot2.TreeId
   JOIN Owner o2 ON ot2.OwnerId = o2.OwnerId
   INNER JOIN c ON c.TreeId = t2.parentid
)
SELECT * FROM t  WHERE t.TreeId = 32800 and t.OwnerId is not NULL
```

It returns back 0 records. It should return back 1.

**Sample Data:**

```
select * from tree where treeid = 32800
union
select * from tree where treeid = 32646
union
select * from tree where treeid = 32645
union
select * from tree where treeid = 32619
union
select * from tree where treeid = 31459
union
select * from tree where treeid = 31458
```

[image]

```
select * from owner
```

[image]

```
select * from dbo.xrefOwnerTree where treeid = 31459
```

[image]

```
WITH c (TreeId, Parentid, level, BranchName, OwnerId) as 
(
   SELECT t.TreeId, t.Parentid, 0 as level, BranchName, o.OwnerId
   FROM Tree t
   JOIN xrefOwnerTree ot ON t.TreeID = ot.TreeId
   JOIN Owner o ON ot.OwnerId = o.OwnerId
   WHERE Parentid is null

   UNION ALL

   SELECT t2.TreeId, t2.parentid, c.level + 1, t2.BranchName, o2.OwnerId
   FROM Tree t2 
   JOIN xrefOwnerTree ot2 ON t2.TreeID = ot2.TreeId
   JOIN Owner o2 ON ot2.OwnerId = o2.OwnerId
   INNER JOIN c ON c.TreeId = t2.parentid
)
SELECT * FROM c
```

[image]

```
SELECT t.TreeId, t.Parentid, 0 as level, BranchName, o.OwnerId
FROM Tree t
JOIN xrefOwnerTree ot ON t.TreeID = ot.TreeId
JOIN Owner o ON ot.OwnerId = o.OwnerId
WHERE Parentid is null
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to change the anchor member to not use `t` as an alias since it is already the name of the CTE. What do you get if you remove the `WHERE` clause from the final `SELECT`? What do you get if you just execute the anchor member from the CTE? Can you post a small set of sample data that illustrates the problem? Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Alias changed.
When I remove the where clause it gives me back nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have your own table. I suggest you have to check your Union one by one like this:

Check it first:

```
SELECT t.TreeId, t.Parentid, 0 as level, BranchName, o.OwnerId
   FROM Tree t
   JOIN xrefOwnerTree ot ON t.TreeID = ot.TreeId
   JOIN Owner o ON ot.OwnerId = o.OwnerId
   WHERE Parentid = 0
```

And then the second one..

Hope it could help.

Comment: When I ran the 1st query, i got nothing (see sample data in update). I couldn't run the second one in isolation because it is dependent on the "with" statement

Comment: yeah seen it, what what result do you want for that particular first query?